# How to notify user that python application is unable to connect

Tags: python, tkinter

This python Tkinter GUI application communicates with an embedded Linux target over a serial port. Is there a way to notify the user, perhaps with a tkMessageBox, if the application is unable to connect to the target using the serial port? A Linux launcher icon on the host is currently used to start this application so no feedback at all is given to the user if it is not possible to make a connection.

```
def initialize(self):
    self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout=1)
    ...
```

> Edit: this is the solution

```
def initialize(self):
    try:
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout=1)
    except:
        tkMessageBox.showerror(title="Error", message="No Connection")
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Did you use library pyserial? You can use exception serial.SerialTimeoutException where 
Exception that is raised on write timeouts.

Comment: @ManuParra Thank you very much. This was my first attempt at Python. SerialTimeoutException returned an AttributeError so I did a `tkMessageBox.showerror` on any exception. I'll add the working solution to the question and if you copy your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use `pyserial` library? It can solve your problem.

You can use exception `serial.SerialTimeoutException` where Exception that is raised on write timeouts.

I hope it was useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the working solution to the original question.